# How let Julia create ./test/runtests.jl in my project directory

Tags: julia

How to let Julia terminal generate ./test/runtests.jl automatically ?

(I am currently using a Julia v1.2.0 on MacOS)

What I've tried:

```
shell> ls
Manifest.toml       Project.toml        src
NewtonRootFinding.ipynb SecantRootFinding.ipynb

shell> cat test/runtest.jl
cat: test/runtest.jl: No such file or directory

(v1.2) pkg> status
    Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.2/Project.toml`
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.20.0
  [438e738f] PyCall v1.91.2
  [d330b81b] PyPlot v2.8.2

(Prob1) pkg> activate ./test
Activating new environment at `~/..../Prob1/test/Project.toml`

shell> ls
Manifest.toml       Project.toml        src
NewtonRootFinding.ipynb SecantRootFinding.ipynb

(test) pkg> status
    Status `~/.../Prob1/test/Project.toml`
  (empty environment)

(test) pkg> add Test
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/.../Prob1/test/Project.toml`
  [8dfed614] + Test 
  Updating `~/.../Prob1/test/Manifest.toml`
  [2a0f44e3] + Base64 
  [8ba89e20] + Distributed 
  [b77e0a4c] + InteractiveUtils 
  [56ddb016] + Logging 
  [d6f4376e] + Markdown 
  [9a3f8284] + Random 
  [9e88b42a] + Serialization 
  [6462fe0b] + Sockets 
  [8dfed614] + Test 

(test) pkg> status
    Status `~/.../test/Project.toml`
  [8dfed614] Test 

(test) pkg> activate .
Activating environment at `~/.../Prob1/Project.toml`

(Prob1) pkg> status
Project Prob1 v0.1.0
    Status `~/.../Prob1/Project.toml`
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.20.0
  [438e738f] PyCall v1.91.2
  [d330b81b] PyPlot v2.8.2
  [8dfed614] Test 

(Prob1) pkg> activate ./test
Activating environment at `~/.../Prob1/test/Project.toml`

shell> cat test/runtests.jl
cat: test/runtests.jl: No such file or directory


shell> tree .
.
├── Manifest.toml
├── NewtonRootFinding.ipynb
├── Project.toml
├── SecantRootFinding.ipynb
├── src
│   └── Prob1.jl
└── test
    ├── Manifest.toml
    └── Project.toml
```

When I typed tree in shell scripting, there is no runtests.jl Julia file in the ./test directory.

I don't know why.

I followed up the Julia Tutorial: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/index.html

But it didn't work.

Comment: I don't use Julia but I think it doesn't generate tests you have to create it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use [PkgTemplates.jl](https://github.com/invenia/PkgTemplates.jl/)

It is actually recommended in the latest version of the [Pkg.jl docs](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/dev/creating-packages/#)
but works with all versions of Julia.

> #### Note
>
> The [PkgTemplates](https://github.com/invenia/PkgTemplates.jl/) package offers a very easy, repeatable, and customizable way to generate the files for a new package. We recommend that you use PkgTemplates for creating new packages instead of using the minimal `pkg> generate` functionality described below.

By my guess, almost the only Julia developers not using it,
are ones that don't know about it. (Hopefully this post will help)

Here is a very barebones example with a simple Template.

```
using PkgTemplates;
template = Template(; user="oxinabox", dir=".");
generate("MyNewPackage", template);
```

See that it creates a `runtests.jl` file:

```
shell> ls ./MyNewPackage/test/
runtests.jl
```

It also sets up git remotes.

But it can do a lot more.
I would at least:

- Include author and lisence
- turn on TravisCI for automatic test running
- Setup Coveralls to report coverage metrics
- setup GitHubPages for Documenter.jl documentation;
  so I tend to use something like:

```
template = Template(;
   user="myusername",
   license="MIT",
   authors=["Lyndon White"],
   dir=".",
   julia_version=v"1.0",
   plugins=[
       TravisCI(),
       Coveralls(),
       GitHubPages(),
   ],
)
```

Comment: OMG, thanks for letting me know ! So, now I can generate test template. And BTW does is the syntax of writing the runtests.jl file the  same as Julia notebook ?

Comment: The way to indicate thanks on stack overflow is to is to press the upvote (and maybe accept) button :-)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question about notebooks, but best to ask it as a seperate question rather than a comment, then you can give full details.

You also might like to julia the JuliaLang slack: https://slackinvite.julialang.org/

Comment: Ok, thanks, I already upvoted your answer, but due to stackoverflow regulations:  "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." so my upvote does not show in public.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that applied on questions you asked too.
Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

@furas is correct. You need to create the `./test/runtests.jl` file yourself. It's **not** created automatically when you use `generate` command in the package manager.

Comment: Oh, so I have to coding my own runtests.jl file on IJulia Notebook ? And one more question what’s difference between Julia file (.jl) and Ipython Notebook file (.ipynb). When I launched IJulia on Jupyter Notebook and created a Julia project it saved as xxxxxxx.ipynb rather than xxxxxxxx.jl